# Change color of certain words in Tkinter Text widget based on position in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, colors, tkinter

I have a tkinter text box, and I want to change the colour of specific words depending in their position in a list. Basically I have the list `foo = [1,4,5,8,9]`, and I want to change the colour of the words which correspond to the numbers in the list. So words in positions 1, 4, 5, 8, and 9 should have their colour changed. I have had a look at different answers, but they operate on the basis of keywords--not the position of a given word.

Comment: Have already tried some code?

Comment: Looked at some but as i said they work off keywords not position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to highlight text is to create a tag, configure the tag with whatever properties that you want (foreground, background, font, etc), and then apply that tag to regions of the text. The rest is just simple math to compute the range of characters to highlight.

```
text = tk.Text(...)
text.tag_configure("highlight", background="yellow")
...
# add the tag "highlight" to the characters between index 3.0 and 4.0
text.tag_add("highlight", "3.0", "4.0")
```

To help with highlighting words, you can use the modifier `"wordstart"` and/or `"wordend"` with an index to get to the start and end of what tcl thinks is the complete word.

```
# add the tag "highlight" to the word at position 4.5
text.tag_add("highlight", "4.5 wordstart", "4.5 wordend")
```

Comment: OK, what do the 3.0 and 4 relate to? Position and line?

Comment: @Pittsy24: A tkinter index is a string in the form `"line.column"`.